# Close nav on link click

Tags: javascript, html, nav

My nav closes when a user clicks the "X" or hits the esc key, I would like it to close when a user clicks a link as well. The nav is constructed as such;

```
<div class="top-bar">
        <button class="top-bar__nav-toggle hamburger" id="top-nav-toggle">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </button>
        <nav class="top-bar__nav collapsed" id="top-bar__nav">
          <ul class="top-bar__nav-list nav-ul">
            <li>
              <a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navlink" href="#Portfolio">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navlink" href="#About">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navlink" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

is styled as such;

```
body {
  background: gray;
}
.top-bar {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 2vw;
}

.top-bar__nav-toggle {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  min-width: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.hamburger {
  height: 4vw;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger span {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 4vw;
}

.hamburger:focus span {
  background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
  outline: none;
}

.hamburger:hover span {
  background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 20%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}
.hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}
.hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 80%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}

.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}
.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}
.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}

.nav-ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-bar__nav {
  background: transparent;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.25s;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}

.top-bar__nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.top-bar__nav-list li {
  text-align: center;
}

.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list a {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.top-bar__nav-list a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 6vw;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.top-bar__nav-list a:hover {
  color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
}

.top-bar__nav-list a:focus {
  color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
  outline: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .top-bar__nav-list {
    align-items: flex-end;
    background: white;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 4vw;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
    max-height: 0;
  }

  .top-bar__nav-list.collapsed {
    padding-right: 6vw;
  }

  .nav-ul li a {
    color: gray;
  }

  .top-bar__nav-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
  body {
  background: gray;
}
.top-bar {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 2vw;
}

.top-bar__nav-toggle {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  min-width: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.hamburger {
  height: 4vw;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger span {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 4vw;
}

.hamburger:focus span {
  background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
  outline: none;
}

.hamburger:hover span {
  background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 20%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}
.hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}
.hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 80%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}

.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}
.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}
.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}

.nav-ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-bar__nav {
  background: transparent;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.25s;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}

.top-bar__nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.top-bar__nav-list li {
  text-align: center;
}

.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list a {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.top-bar__nav-list a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 6vw;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.top-bar__nav-list a:hover {
  color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
}

.top-bar__nav-list a:focus {
  color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
  outline: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .top-bar__nav-list {
    align-items: flex-end;
    background: white;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 4vw;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
    max-height: 0;
  }

  .top-bar__nav-list.collapsed {
    padding-right: 6vw;
  }

  .nav-ul li a {
    color: gray;
  }

  .top-bar__nav-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

and its functionality comes from this code;

```
(function () {
  if (document.querySelector("#top-nav-toggle")) {
    var navToggle = document.querySelector("#top-nav-toggle");

    function watchNavClose(e) {
      var topNav = document.querySelector(".top-bar");
      if (!e.path.includes(topNav)) {
        openCloseNav();
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
      }
    }

    function openCloseNav() {
      var navToggle = document.querySelector("#top-nav-toggle");

      if (!navToggle.classList.contains("closed")) {
        navToggle.classList.add("closed");
        document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.remove("collapsed");
        document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
      } else {
        document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.add("collapsed");
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
        document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        navToggle.classList.remove("closed");
        }
      }

      document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) {
          document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
          document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
          navToggle.classList.remove("closed");
          document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.add("collapsed");
        }
      })

      navToggle.addEventListener("click", openCloseNav);
  }
})

();
```

I am mostly building through tutorials and such and I have tried figuring it out through similar questions here, but I am new to this and couldn't figure out how to translate it to my code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide your CSS as well? it makes it easier for us to recreate your navbar and work with it because then we have the UI visually .

Comment: Even with this CSS, all I could see was the `ul` and the body is in grey color. However, what you are asking to do is possible, all you have to do is select all `a` elements, then loop over them and add to each an event listener of a click, the callback for this event listener is a function that removes the class that makes your navbar visible.

if you don't know how to do this yourself, I can write it as an answer for you.

Comment: I think thats because its responsive and turns to the hamburger menu when it gets smaller. I probably should have simplified that for my question. The answer below works for me. Is that the solution you would have used?

Comment: Im waiting to be able to post another question, but I am also trying to delay the font-size from getting smaller until the menu is gone if you have any ideas for that.

Comment: You have to use Javascript. In the same event which closes the nav menu (whichever it is), you can add another line saying: `element.style.fontSize`: `yourCustomSize`. if many different elements that all over the page and can't inherit the font size from each other, you can also select them all as you did with the links, loop over them, and do that same line for each element inside the loop. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added separate event listners for the `<a>` tag using `querySelectorAll` and run a function which closes `nav` on listening to click event

```js
(function() {
  if (document.querySelector("#top-nav-toggle")) {
    var navToggle = document.querySelector("#top-nav-toggle");

    function watchNavClose(e) {
      var topNav = document.querySelector(".top-bar");
      if (!e.path.includes(topNav)) {
        openCloseNav();
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
      }
    }

    function openCloseNav() {
      var navToggle = document.querySelector("#top-nav-toggle");

      if (!navToggle.classList.contains("closed")) {
        navToggle.classList.add("closed");
        document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.remove("collapsed");
        document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
      } else {
        document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.add("collapsed");
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
        document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        navToggle.classList.remove("closed");
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
        document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        navToggle.classList.remove("closed");
        document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.add("collapsed");
      }
    })

    navToggle.addEventListener("click", openCloseNav);

    document.querySelectorAll(".navlink")[0].addEventListener("click", closeNav);
    document.querySelectorAll(".navlink")[1].addEventListener("click", closeNav);
    document.querySelectorAll(".navlink")[2].addEventListener("click", closeNav);
    document.querySelectorAll(".navlink")[3].addEventListener("click", closeNav);

    function closeNav() {
      var navToggle = document.querySelector("#top-nav-toggle");
      document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.add("collapsed");
      document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
      document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
      navToggle.classList.remove("closed");
    }

  }
})

();
```

```css
      body {
  background: gray;
}

.top-bar {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 2vw;
}

.top-bar__nav-toggle {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  min-width: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.hamburger {
  height: 4vw;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger span {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 4vw;
}

.hamburger:focus span {
  background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
  outline: none;
}

.hamburger:hover span {
  background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 20%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 80%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}

.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}

.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}

.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}

.nav-ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-bar__nav {
  background: transparent;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.25s;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}

.top-bar__nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.top-bar__nav-list li {
  text-align: center;
}

.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list a {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.top-bar__nav-list a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 6vw;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.top-bar__nav-list a:hover {
  color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
}

.top-bar__nav-list a:focus {
  color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
  outline: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .top-bar__nav-list {
    align-items: flex-end;
    background: white;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 4vw;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
    max-height: 0;
  }
  .top-bar__nav-list.collapsed {
    padding-right: 6vw;
  }
  .nav-ul li a {
    color: gray;
  }
  .top-bar__nav-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    body {
      background: gray;
    }
    .top-bar {
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-right: 2vw;
    }
    .top-bar__nav-toggle {
      background: transparent;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: none;
      font-size: 50px;
      min-width: 5vw;
      text-align: center;
      transition: 0.25s;
    }
    .hamburger {
      height: 4vw;
      position: relative;
    }
    .hamburger span {
      background: white;
      border-radius: 25%;
      height: 2px;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 4vw;
    }
    .hamburger:focus span {
      background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
      outline: none;
    }
    .hamburger:hover span {
      background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
    }
    .hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
      top: 20%;
      transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
    }
    .hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
      top: 50%;
      transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
    }
    .hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
      top: 80%;
      transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
    }
    .hamburger.closed span:nth-child(1) {
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
      transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
    }
    .hamburger.closed span:nth-child(2) {
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
      transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
    }
    .hamburger.closed span:nth-child(3) {
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
      transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
    }
    .nav-ul {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .top-bar__nav {
      background: transparent;
      max-height: 400px;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 0.25s;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
      transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    }
    .top-bar__nav-list {
      list-style: none;
    }
    .top-bar__nav-list li {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .collapsed .top-bar__nav-list a {
      font-size: 2vw;
    }
    .top-bar__nav-list a {
      border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 6vw;
      padding-left: 3vw;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.25s;
    }
    .top-bar__nav-list a:hover {
      color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
    }
    .top-bar__nav-list a:focus {
      color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
      outline: none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .top-bar__nav-list {
        align-items: flex-end;
        background: white;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-right: 4vw;
        position: fixed;
        transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
        max-height: 0;
      }
      .top-bar__nav-list.collapsed {
        padding-right: 6vw;
      }
      .nav-ul li a {
        color: gray;
      }
      .top-bar__nav-toggle {
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <button class="top-bar__nav-toggle hamburger" id="top-nav-toggle">
          Close
        </button>
  <nav class="top-bar__nav collapsed" id="top-bar__nav">
    <ul class="top-bar__nav-list nav-ul">
      <li>
        <a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="navlink" href="#Portfolio">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="navlink" href="#About">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="navlink" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```